# Using CMake FindPython() with "Development" component when cross-compiling

Tags: python, cmake, cross-compiling

I have a CMake toolchain file containing the following

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(target_triplet "arm-linux-gnueabihf")
set(target_root /srv/chroot/raspbian)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${target_triplet}-gcc CACHE FILEPATH "C compiler")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${target_triplet}-g++ CACHE FILEPATH "C++ compiler")

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${target_root})

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE ${target_triplet})

# Look for the headers and libraries in the target system.
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${target_root})

# Setting the root path is not enough to make pkg-config work.
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_DIR} "")
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR} "${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}/usr/lib/${target_triplet}/pkgconfig")
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR} ${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH})

# Don't look for programs in the root path (these are ARM programs, they won't
# run on the build machine)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# Only look for libraries, headers and packages in the sysroot, don't look on
# the build machine
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

This relies on having a working Raspbian installation under `/srv/chroot/raspbian` and is supposed to make it possible to easily use its system libraries. This works fine for "simple" libraries after setting `PKG_CONFIG_XXX` like above, but fails for

```
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Development.Module REQUIRED)
```

with the following errors:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS Development.Module)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake:3217 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPython3.cmake:490 (include)
  Python3API/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)
```

I'm a bit lost in 3421 lines of `FindPython/Support.cmake` module, so I don't understand why it doesn't find the headers and, unfortunately, the error is not very helpful and there doesn't seem any way to turn on debugging for this code. But it seems like it doesn't look inside the chroot containing the target system at all, because it's supposed to use `${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE}-python-config` if it's available, and a file with this name does exist in `${target_root}/usr/bin`, but somehow it doesn't seem to be found. I've tried setting `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM` to `ONLY`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is it possible to make this work without manually setting `Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS` and all the other variables? Please note that I really want to use the target root and not install the packages on the host system, as they are not available for it in the versions old enough to ensure compatibility with the system being targeted.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, doing

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM ONLY)
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Development.Module REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
```

does work for Python 3. Unfortunately if you still need to support Python 2 too, it doesn't work for it because `python2.7-config` doesn't behave correctly when invoked from outside the sysroot and returns wrong paths with a duplicate sysroot path in them. I couldn't find any workaround for this and ended up hardcoding Python 2 include directories.